# Compatibility of classifying space with inner-hom?

Tags: ct.category-theory, at.algebraic-topology, model-categories, simplicial-stuff

Let $\mathbf{sTop}$ be the functor category $\mathbf{Top}^{{\mathbf{\Delta}}^{\textit{op}}}$, and let $\mathbf{sCat}$ be the functor category 
$\mathbf{Cat}^{{\mathbf{\Delta}}^{\textit{op}}}$, and let $B:\mathbf{Cat}\rightarrow\mathbf{Top}$ be the classifying space functor (take nerve then realize).  How do
$B\underline{\mathbf{sCat}}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D})$ and $\underline{\mathbf{sTop}}(B\mathcal{C},B\mathcal{D})$ compare?

I think they are weakly equivalent (in the Reedy model structure), and I'm hoping that there might be a trivial cofibration between them.  Anyone know a reference for something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's something easier. Let $C$ and $D$ be categories, and ask: is there an equivalence between $B\underline{\mathrm{Cat}}(C,D)$ (the classifying space of the functor category) and $\underline{\mathrm{Top}}(BC,BD)$ (the mapping space between two classifying spaces)?

In general, the answer is no.  For instance, let $C$  be the category $(x\rightrightarrows y)$ with two objects and two non-identity arrows from $x$ to $y$.  Then $BC$ is a circle, and $\underline{\mathrm{Top}}(BC,BC)$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}\times S^1$, whereas $B\underline{\mathrm{Cat}}(C,C)$ is not (it has only finitely many components, for instance).

Taking constant simplicial objects should provide a counterexample to your claim, unless I've misunderstood what you are asking for.

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I confess that I didn't ask that easier question because I thought I had checked that case.  Since in the analogous case for nerve you get an isomorphism, the problem has to be with realization.  My 'proof' relied on the simplicial map
$$
\mathbf{sSet}(S_{\bullet}\times\delta(k),T_{\bullet})
\rightarrow \mathbf{Top}(|S_{\bullet}\times\delta(k)|,|T_{\bullet}|)
$$
being a weak equivalence, which is clearly not true.
The issue that your example highlights seems to be that $B$ doesn't respect the direction of arrows.  So might the (simpler) version be true for groupoids?

Comment: Yep, the simpler version will be true if $C$ and $D$ are groupoids (in fact, even if only $D$ is a groupoid).